# spring adding external jar with controller not working

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have made a Java project having spring controller that handle url

Here is the controller code

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;


@EnableWebMvc
@Controller
public class SmartContentValidator {

@RequestMapping(value = "/validate")
public String validate() {
    System.out.println("Yo");

    return "YO";
}
}
```

Then I exported above java project as jar file.
Then created a new web project and added the above jar in build path. Here is the web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>SmartContentValidatorTest</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=" 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com" />
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now when I try to hit http://localhost:8080/project_name/validate

it shows 404-not found on browser and

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SmartContentValidatorTest/validate/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

in my eclipse console.

What is the issue? Am I missing something?

**Edit**

Project Structure
[image]

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem. please write an answer if so. I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpfull you just need to setting up your ${CATALINA_BASE}/conf/Catalina/localhost/{YOUR_APP_NAME}.xml here my gist with examples https://gist.github.com/durdyev/542dffb60beb30f5c6ce293418555ef7

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it helps with your case but I think that in standalone application there would be an issue as `@EnableWebMvc` should be used with Java config - class annotated with `@Configuration`, not with `@Controller` bean.

As you use xml config you can try put `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable for more details.

You would also need to provide your application context as dispatcher servlet param like in example http://docs.spring.io/spring-flex/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/ch02s02.html:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is caused by Spring not correctly finding your controller. If you enable DEBUG logging Spring will log what beans are registered when you start the application.

If it is correctly loading your controller then check that your root path is correct (I think this is your war name by default) which again should be displayed in the logging during startup.